# updating datagridview table

Tags: c#, datagridview, arraylist

I'm new at this programming thing and it's fun!

At the moment I'm looking at the DataGridView and arraylists.

In my array I have names and addresses and such...

and by a click of a button I set the datasource for the datagridview to my arraylist like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = logik.kundekartotek.arrKunder;
    }
```

but when I add some new information to my arraylist I need to update the datagridview..

but how do I do that?

I found a solution:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null; 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = logik.kundekartotek.arrKunder;
    }
```

but that doesn't seem right..

Comment: Why do you mean by 'that doesn't seem right??'

Comment: it seems strange that i have to remove and then re-add the datasource

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = logik.kundekartotek.arrKunder;
    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

EndEdit is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.endedit.aspx?ppud=4).

Comment: Same here... I'm going to assume Xtudio means EndEdit and update the post. (EndEdit method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.endedit.aspx?ppud=4 )

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to add `new row` to the `DataGridView` yourself. On adding `new item` to the `array` that you have, you could do,

```
  int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();//i is the index of the new row added

    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = val1;
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = val2;
```

If lets suppose, one of your column `value` is of `DateTime`, you could do

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use an `ArrayList` as your `DataSource` then what you are doing is the best way of updating the displayed informmation **however** there are collection types that are far better for using as the `DataSource` which have been designed to support two way databinding.

The first thing to look at is the generic `BindingList<T>` collection. It is described fully [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) on MSDN.

With a `BindingList<T>` instead of the `ArrayList` when you add new objects to the list (using the .Add() method) they will automatically appear in the `DataGridView`.

Once you have started using that you will probably want more features such as sorting the grid by column - browse through MSDN for more examples of what is possible.

(another `DataSource` option that gives advanced functions is the `DataTable` just as with the `BindingList<T>` when you add an item to a `DataTable` it appears in the `DataGridView` but I'd recommend using the list, datatables either bind you to a specific data access technololgy or force you to jump through a lot of hoops).